# Difference between "All is well" and "All are fine"

Tags: differences

Always had this confusion !

In speaking,

- All is well
- All are fine

I heard a lot of people using above two these sentences many times so I got confused of the usage of "is" and "are" after "ALL".

When should we use "is" and when should we use "are" after "ALL" ?

Comment: *All* does not necessarily signify a large number of people. *All **of them*** might; *All **of it*** surely does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* can be used to mean either: (1) *every one (of some items)* or (2) *a single substance in its entirety*. In the former case, you would use *all are* since the topic includes every one of some set of items. In the latter case, you would use *all is* since there is only one item or substance for which the entire amount is being addressed.

For example:

`Every one of these apples is good. All are good.`

`Everyone is visiting today. All are visiting.`

`Every bit of this pie is tasty. All is tasty.`

`Everything is doing well today. All is well.`